# Older Magic Chef Dishwasher Won't Drain - How to Test Motor/Pump Assembly?

Tags: dishwasher, testing

I have a Magic Chef CDB4000TQ0 dishwasher that is not draining. Based on my research, a common cause of this is a faulty pump/motor assembly (part # WPW10247394 for entire assembly; motor part # 8283457). However, I have yet to find consistent guidance on how test this part, specifically what is the expected resistance when tested with a multi-meter?

I would appreciate any guidance on how to test this part, as well any items I may test to resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First test would be to use multimeter and see if the pump gets power when it supposed to do so, in the program mode.

From here we have

1- has power but not running, so it is the motor it self

2- has no power, it is the control relay from the programer

3- Motor is turning but pump is not pumping, it is the motor to pump connection shaft, or the pump it self.

Resistance meter will not give any usable results.